# Trouble with aggregation in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to show, for the past month, the highest values, across 10 groups that have multiple values in the month, per group.

I'm sort of on my way by;

```
SELECT 
    Group, MAX(Value), Date
FROM
    <relevant tables>
GROUP BY
  Group, Date
```

But this returns everything from the groups, I need the highest from each across that period (e.g. just **'0007'    '1002415.59'    '2016-11-11'** for one of the 0007 lines)

```
0007    27456.14    2016-11-07
0082    2406.30     2016-11-07
0007    33038.34    2016-11-08
0082    569.37      2016-11-08
0007    1274.78     2016-11-09
0088    2266.00     2016-11-09
0007    124.57      2016-11-10
6082    2407.27     2016-11-10
0007    1002415.59  2016-11-11
0882    90.30       2016-11-11
0477    67.90       2016-11-12
0067    66.33       2016-11-13
```

Struggling a bit with this level of aggregation!

I'm happy with at least a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: please tag the dbms being used..

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The solution may depend on the product's functionality.)

Comment: Apologies, added!

Comment: You want the maximum date with its value or the maximum value with its date? (Your example matches both cases.)

Comment: The maximum value, with it's date.
I'm just playing around with the suggestions made below at the moment, it's going a bit better.

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with: `GROUP BY x, y, z` means "I want one result row per x-y-z combination". You are using `GROUP BY Group, Date`, so you shouldn't be surprised to get one result row per Group and Date. It would have to be `GROUP BY Group` to get one result row per Group.

However, you are not looking for an aggregation at all (i.e. look at the records of one Group and collect data from them). All you want to do is show certain records and others not. This is done in `WHERE`. In order to rank your records you'd use `ROW_NUMBER` (in other scenarios you might want `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK` instead).

```
SELECT [Group], Value, [Date]
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    [Group], Value, [Date],
    row_number() over (partition by [Group] order by Value desc) as rn
  FROM <relevant tables>
) data
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked, and I understand it too, very useful going forwards!

Answer (score 2):

The typical way to do this is to use the ANSI standard `row_number` function:

```
with t as (
      SELECT . . .
      FROM <relevant tables>
     )
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by grp order by date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

The CTE is just used to encapsulate your current logic.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit lengthy but it should help  you understand how to split it into small parts. If you have performance considerations, the query can be re-written and optimized.

SELECT 
        Group , MAX(Value) as MaximumValue, Date INTO #tmpGroupMaximumValue
    FROM
        
    GROUP BY
      Group, Date

```
SELECT 
Group,DENSE_RANK() OVER (
        PARTITION BY A.Group ORDER BY A.MaximumValue DESC
        ) as [MaxGroupValueRank], [Date] INTO #tmpB
 FROM #tmpGroupMaximumValue A


SELECT * FROM #tmpB WHERE [MaxGroupValueRank] = 1
```